# How to point at plugin (Bukkit)

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I need something like: `Plugin plugin = this plugin` but I cant find anything that points to this plugin so I ask here.

My Code:

```
`package cz.untitled.main;

import cz.untitled.Untitled;
import io.papermc.paper.plugin.configuration.PluginMeta;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.Server;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Item;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.generator.BiomeProvider;
import org.bukkit.generator.ChunkGenerator;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.metadata.FixedMetadataValue;
import org.bukkit.metadata.MetadataValue;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class serverselectcommand implements CommandExecutor {

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(@NotNull CommandSender commandSender, @NotNull Command command, @NotNull String s, @NotNull String[] strings) {
        if(commandSender instanceof Player)
        {
            Player p = (Player) commandSender;
            Inventory inventory = Bukkit.createInventory(p, 9 * 6, ChatColor.GRAY + "Výběr serveru");

            ItemStack nothing = new ItemStack(Material.GRAY_STAINED_GLASS_PANE);
            ItemMeta nothingmeta = nothing.getItemMeta();
            nothingmeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + " ");
            nothing.setItemMeta(nothingmeta);
            ItemStack isword = new ItemStack(Material.IRON_SWORD);
            ItemMeta iswordmeta = isword.getItemMeta();
            iswordmeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GOLD + "M" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "i" + ChatColor.GOLD + "n" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "i" + ChatColor.GOLD + "h" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "r" + ChatColor.GOLD + "y");
            isword.setItemMeta(iswordmeta);
            ItemStack grassblock = new ItemStack(Material.GRASS_BLOCK);
            ItemMeta grassblockmeta = grassblock.getItemMeta();
            grassblockmeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "S" + ChatColor.GREEN + "u" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "r" + ChatColor.GREEN + "v" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "i" + ChatColor.GREEN + "v" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "a" + ChatColor.GREEN + "l");
            grassblock.setItemMeta(grassblockmeta);
            ItemStack ob = new ItemStack(Material.STONE);
            ItemMeta obmeta = ob.getItemMeta();
            obmeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "O" + ChatColor.BLUE + "n" + ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "e" + ChatColor.BLUE + "b" + ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "l" + ChatColor.BLUE + "o" + ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "c" + ChatColor.BLUE + "k");
            ob.setItemMeta(obmeta);

            inventory.setItem(0, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(1, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(2, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(3, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(4, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(5, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(6, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(7, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(8, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(9, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(10, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(11, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(12, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(13, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(14, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(15, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(16, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(17, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(18, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(19, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(20, isword);
            inventory.setItem(21, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(22, grassblock);
            inventory.setItem(23, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(24, ob);
            inventory.setItem(25, nothing);
            inventory.setItem(26, nothing);
            p.openInventory(inventory);
            
            //p.setMetadata("OpenedMenu", new FixedMetadataValue(plugin, "main"));
        }
        else
        {
            Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().log(Level.INFO, ChatColor.RED + "Oh, You must be player to execute this!");
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
MyPluginClass myPlugin = MyPluginClass.getPlugin(MyPluginClass.class); // returns instance of MyPluginClass
```

Replace `MyPluginClass` with the class name of the class that extends `JavaPlugin` and it will return its instance.

Just remeber, class names should be PascalCase - in your case `serverselectcommand` should be `ServerSelectCommand`. Stick to that naming convention and you won't have issues in the future.

Comment: Are you sure? `MyPluginClass.java` isn't something that will work. And class names have nothing to do with any actual problems. You can write them however you like, even though LikeThis is the most common way.

Comment: It was meant to be class, my bad. Anyways, everyone will make fool of you when you publish a library and the class names are lower case. 
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html